# Ajax-post generate url-link forgetts to make the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ive got this ajax method that opens a dialog with a url-link in it. The problem is that when i first opens it it works just fine. But if i close it and opens it again it doesn't generate the url-link. Still i know that it makes the url in the administationcontroller so that is not the problem.

```
$('#generate-report-link').live('click', function () {
    $('#report-link').prop('href', "");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Administration/Administration/GenerateReportLink',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ReportLink').removeClass('hidden-div');
            $('#ReportLink').dialog({
                width: 600,
                height: 166,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Rapportlänk',
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    if (data.url.length > 0) {
                        $('#report-link-header').html('Använd följande länk för att ge access till rapportvyn:');
                        $('#report-link').prop('href', data.url);
                        $('#report-link').prop('target', '_blank');
                        $('#report-link').html(data.url);
                    } else {
                        $('#report-link-header').html('Det finns ingen rapport användare för er företag, vänligen kontakta system administratören.');
                        $('#report-link').removeAttr('href');
                        $('#report-link').removeAttr('target');
                        $('#report-link').html("");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think after the click event add below line. You have to destroy the dialog each time before creating it again.

```
//after this line
$('#generate-report-link').live('click', function () {
// add this
**$('#ReportLink').dialog('destroy').remove();**
// MORE CODE
```

Comment: This didn't work. It didn't open the dialog at all :(

Comment: oops. Can you please create a jsfiddle. I can check that.

Comment: I used your destroy method in the close function, i also relized i forgot to make a dialog-close function and just a button-close function. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to the cache ? Try to append tstamp to url like this :

```
$('#generate-report-link').live('click', function () {
    $('#report-link').prop('href', "");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Administration/Administration/GenerateReportLink?'+new Date().getTime(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ReportLink').removeClass('hidden-div');
            $('#ReportLink').dialog({
                width: 600,
                height: 166,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Rapportlänk',
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    if (data.url.length > 0) {
                        $('#report-link-header').html('Använd följande länk för att ge access till rapportvyn:');
                        $('#report-link').prop('href', data.url);
                        $('#report-link').prop('target', '_blank');
                        $('#report-link').html(data.url);
                    } else {
                        $('#report-link-header').html('Det finns ingen rapport användare för er företag, vänligen kontakta system administratören.');
                        $('#report-link').removeAttr('href');
                        $('#report-link').removeAttr('target');
                        $('#report-link').html("");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Now it can't reach the controller method. Do i need to have a datetime imparameter on the controller method?

Comment: I'm not sure if thats the reason .. but try this : url: '/Administration/Administration/GenerateReportLink?t='+new Date().getTime(),

Comment: Now it almost works. If i close it it doesn't add the url-link but if i close that and opens it again it works. :S

Comment: I realized it worked like that before i added t='+new Date().getTime()